# Static options menu

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to create a static options menu for all my activity screens. I dont want to override `onCreateOptionsMenu()` in each activity.

Since `Menu` class is an interface with a huge number of methods, its difficult to create a static object of the implementing class.

Any other way of doing the same?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I read your question correctly you want the *same* menu in all your Activities.  I can think of two ways to do this:

1. Create a subclass of `Activity` that implements `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()` (and possibly  `onPrepareOptionsMenu`).  Then have all your `Activity` classes extend this subclass.
2. Create a static method somewhere called something like `populateOptionsMenu()` that takes a `Menu` (and probably a `Context`) as arguments.  Your `Activity` classes can then call this from their `onCreateOptionsMenu()` methods to populate the `Menu`.  You'd also need a corresponding `processItemSelected()` static method for when items were clicked.

Option 1 seems best as it wouldn't require the same bolierplate in your Activities to call the static methods.

Comment: Do you mean Option 2 wouldn't require the same bolierplate?

Comment: The first solution is not good idea because it requires inheritance. What if my Activities are other than Activity (FragmentActivity, ListActivity, ...)? I think we should void inheritance when possible.

Comment: @Emerald214 in that case, can't you use "implements"?

Comment: how to integrate global options menu with cart icon with count for that how can i implement globally with count please help me