# Set a global menu on an Android application

Tags: android, menu, global

> **Duplicate:** [static options menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070022/static-options-menu)

Hi everyone,

I know how to create a menu in my application with an icon and text on each "button" of the menu, but this menu is only visible on the activity where I created it...
I would like to know if it is possible to create a global menu which would be accessible from all activities?
thank you

Comment: Have look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070022/static-options-menu

Comment: Well yeah i saw this before posting but my problem is that with solution 1, I have to extend the subclass and my activities are already extending other classes, most of the time... so no multiple inheritance...

Comment: Ok then didn't find this topic while searching with "global menu".
My topic will add some tag to this research.
Thx Dave, works perfectly now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to know if it is possible
>   to create a global menu which would be
>   accessible from all activities?

Not really. Since you didn't like the inheritance solution, the only alternative is to consolidate the menu creation and handling code in one place (e.g., static methods). You would still need to implement the callbacks on each activity (e.g., `onHandleOptionsMenu()`) and route them to the static common implementation.

Comment: Yeah thx, I finally chose this way (inheritance) of doing as I said on the other post.
thx for help