# Android: Static options menu giving a null pointer

Tags: android, static, menu, global

I am trying to do the same as the question in here.

[Static options menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070022/static-options-menu)

However, following the 2nd option of the 1st answer gives me a null pointer exception. Basically it does not work. What am I missing. Below are my code files.

Thank you very much in advance.

**AppSetup.java**

```
    package com.connectionmanager.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AppSetup extends Activity implements OnClickListener  
{
    private AcmMenu acmMenu;
    private Context appContext;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.app_setup);

        appContext = this.getApplicationContext();
        Log.v("Hello","Bringing up application setup Dialog box");

        //Set up buttons
        Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonSave);
        Button btnContinue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonContinue);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnContinue.setOnClickListener(this);

        this.resetLabels();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            this.finish();
            Log.v("Hello","Back key pressed");
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        acmMenu = new AcmMenu(menu,this.getApplicationContext());
        acmMenu.inflate();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        acmMenu.onSelectedItem(item,appContext );
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(arg0.getId() == (R.id.ButtonSave))
        {
            // Save information and then finish.
            AppDatabase db = new AppDatabase(this.getApplicationContext());

            db.setHostname( ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_hostname)).getText().toString());
            db.setRegistrationUrl(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_registration)).getText().toString());
            db.setSsid(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_ssid)).getText().toString());

            db.closeDb();

            this.resetLabels();
        }
        if(arg0.getId() == (R.id.ButtonContinue))
        {
            this.finish();
        }
    }

    private void resetLabels()
    {
        //Get and set existing values from the database.
        AppDatabase db = new AppDatabase(this.getApplicationContext());
        Log.v("Hello","Hostname from app:" +db.getHostname() );

        TextView hostname_current = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_hostname_current);
        hostname_current.setText("(Current: "+db.getHostname()+")");
        ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_hostname)).setText(db.getHostname());

        TextView registration_current = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_registration_current);
        registration_current.setText("(Current: "+db.getRegistrationUrl()+")");
        ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_registration)).setText(db.getRegistrationUrl());

        TextView chat_current = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_chat_current);
        //chat_current.setText("(Current: "+db.getRegistrationUrl()+")");
        //((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_chat)).setText(db.getRegistrationUrl());

        TextView ssid_current = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_ssid_current);
        ssid_current.setText("(Current: "+db.getSsid()+")");
        ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_ssid)).setText(db.getSsid());

        db.closeDb();
    }
}
```

**AcmMenu.java**

```
package com.connectionmanager.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class AcmMenu extends Activity{

    private Menu acmMenu;
    private static Context classContext;

    public AcmMenu(Menu menu, Context cont)
    {
        classContext = cont;
        acmMenu = menu;
    }

    public void inflate()
    {
        if (classContext == null)
        {
            Log.v("Hello","Context null");
        }
        else
        {
            MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(classContext);
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.acm_menu, acmMenu);
        }

    }

    public void onSelectedItem(MenuItem item, Context con)
    {
        Log.v("Hello","Starting activity");
        Intent gotoHelpScreen = new Intent(con, Help.class);

        try
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(con, NewUserAccount.class));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.v("Hello","Exception: " + e.toString());
        }


        /*/ Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) 
        {
        case R.id.menu_wifi:
            toggleWifi();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_account:
            gotoAccounts();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_help:
            showHelp();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }*/
    }

    private void toggleWifi()
    {

    }

    private void gotoAccounts()
    {

    }

    private void showHelp()
    {

    }
}
```

**Help.java**

```
package com.connectionmanager.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Help extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.help);

    }

}
```

**Manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.connectionmanager.app"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name=".CMapp"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".NewUserAccount" />
        <activity android:name=".FoundSavedUser" />
        <activity android:name=".AppSetup" />
        <activity android:name=".Help" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Stacktrace

```
 05-27 12:07:03.930: WARN/Server(7134): Addition of the standard header "cache-control" is not allowed. Please use the equivalent property in the Restlet API.
05-27 12:07:03.930: WARN/Server(7134): Addition of the standard header "expires" is not allowed. Please use the equivalent property in the Restlet API.
05-27 12:07:03.961: WARN/System.err(8135): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-27 12:07:03.961: WARN/System.err(8135):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2890)
05-27 12:07:03.961: WARN/System.err(8135):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2996)
05-27 12:07:03.961: WARN/System.err(8135):     at com.connectionmanager.app.AcmMenu.onSelectedItem(AcmMenu.java:43)
05-27 12:07:03.961: WARN/System.err(8135):     at com.connectionmanager.app.AppSetup.onOptionsItemSelected(AppSetup.java:61)
05-27 12:07:03.961: WARN/System.err(8135):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2234)
05-27 12:07:03.970: WARN/System.err(8135):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:747)
05-27 12:07:03.970: WARN/System.err(8135):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:160)
05-27 12:07:03.970: WARN/System.err(8135):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:886)
05-27 12:07:03.970: WARN/System.err(8135):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:545)
05-27 12:07:03.970: WARN/System.err(8135):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
05-27 12:07:03.970: WARN/System.err(8135):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8867)
05-27 12:07:03.970: WARN/System.err(8135):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-27 12:07:03.970: WARN/System.err(8135):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-27 12:07:03.970: WARN/System.err(8135):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
05-27 12:07:03.970: WARN/System.err(8135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5068)
05-27 12:07:03.970: WARN/System.err(8135):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 12:07:03.970: WARN/System.err(8135):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-27 12:07:03.970: WARN/System.err(8135):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
05-27 12:07:03.970: WARN/System.err(8135):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
05-27 12:07:03.970: WARN/System.err(8135):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-27 12:07:03.980: VERBOSE/WindowManager(1292): Remove Window{4757e618 AtchDlg:com.connectionmanager.app/com.connectionmanager.app.AppSetup paused=false}: mSurface=Surface(name=AtchDlg:com.connectionmanager.app/com.connectionmanager.app.AppSetup, identity=1792) mExiting=false isAnimating=false app-animation=null inPendingTransaction=false mDisplayFrozen=false
05-27 12:07:03.990: ERROR/WindowManager(1292): return in removeWindowLocked
05-27 12:07:04.000: DEBUG/InputManagerService(1292): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@475c3990
```

Comment: What is the error message in logcat?

Comment: This is what I get on the LogCat: 05-25 19:34:53.096: VERBOSE/Hello(303): Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: What is the line number?  In what file?  What line does it point to?

Comment: It does not give me line number as it is just an exception. I get the message as I have sorted all exceptions and comments by 'Hello' tag. But as far as the code goes. The exception is from "public boolean onSelectedItem(MenuItem item)" method of AcmMenu.java class. Occurs right at the time of starting the activity.

Comment: I have never seen an Exception without a line number.  I can't help without knowing what line is failing.

Comment: May be it is not enabled in my Eclipse, do you know how can I do that. I am using LogCat to view it. As far as where it fails, it fails when i try to "startActivity(gotoHelpScreen);" which you can see in AcmMenu.java class. I have verified by using log print statments before and after it.

Comment: Okay. So finally figured out where my stack trace was being printed out.

Comment: You have a try/catch around `startActivity(gotoHelpScreen);` but the NPE is still escaping.. that doesn't seem right.  Have you modified the code at all?

Comment: Yes, I just made an edit. The change was in AcmMenu.java. Basically I was using another Activity (which i used before and is working) to test if it was activity that was causing problem

Comment: Sorry. I will re-edit all the classes so that you have better idea. Give me a moment

Comment: Okay. Updated all code here. So the stack trace is now with the above code files.

Comment: Very odd.  The code looks clean. Can you set a debug point at `startActivity` and debug through to see if the Context is null? that's the only thing I can think to do at this point.

Comment: I could not upload image because I need more rep, but yes, I did debug it does show a value for not only Context but the new Intent too.

Comment: I guess i will just have to go with the separate menu on each screen now. Thanks for all the help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
 public void onSelectedItem(MenuItem item, Context con){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(con, NewUserAccount.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        con.startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();      
     }
```